# Android RxJava how to check if an object is on the list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, mutablelist

I have this code:

```
var kitchenList: MutableList<Dish> = ArrayList()
var intervalObser = interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

        
        intervalObser.subscribe({
            fromIterable(orderList)
                .filter { it.status.equals("to create")
                }
                .subscribe({
                    kitchenList.add(it)
                    Log.d("add", "success")
                },{Log.d("add", "error")})
        },{})
```

where he finds meals to be done and adds them to the list in the kitchen every second but
how to check if the data about a specific id is already on the kitchenList using rxJava? And how to stop adding 10 dishes and restart adding after removing one or more.

Is there any other method responsible for the repetition than the interval used above?

Comment: Not sure why you'd need RxJava for that. You could use `filter` or `any` on the kotlin lists.

Comment: this is my task in college :/

Comment: Could you post the original task description (in english)?

Comment: @akarnokd isn't this just a simple if statement ? if(kitchenlist doesn't have item) { kitchenList.add(it)} ? already doing half of that in the subscribe

Comment: From an orderlist with 20 dishes, add them to the kitchenlist, making sure that the dish from the orderlist is not already on the kitchenlist, checking that the status of the dish is "to create" and stopping adding when the kitchenlist has 10 items. 3 dishes from the orderlist have the same id. When you change the status of a dish to "created" in the orderlist and kitchenlist, remove the dish from the kitchenlist and add another dish.

Comment: All operations except status changes should be done using rxjava. Predict the possibility of changing the orderlist from outside (more / fewer dishes, different / identical id etc.).
The "dish" object has id, name, price, status.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (although it is a bit convoluted for producing the required behavior):

```kotlin
val orderList: MutableList<Dish> = ArrayList()
val kitchenList: MutableList<Dish> = ArrayList()

fun setCreated(id: Int) : Unit {
    Observable.fromIterable(orderList)
    .filter { it.id == id }
    .doOnNext { it.status = "created" }
    .subscribe()

    Observable.fromIterable(kitchenList)
    .filter { it.id != id }
    .toList()
    .doOnSuccess { 
        kitchenList.clear()
        kitchenList.addAll(it)
    }
    .subscribe()
 
    updateKitchen()
}
fun updateKitchen() : Unit {
    Observable.fromIterable(orderList)
    .filter { it.status == "to create" }
    .flatMapMaybe { outer ->
         Observable.fromIterable(kitchenList)
         .any { it.id == outer.id }
         .filter { !it }
         .map { outer }
    }
    .takeWhile { kitchenList.size < 10 }
    .doOnNext { kitchenList.add(it) }
    .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: that's what i needed, thank you very much